# Laravel Not working as CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: reactjs, cors, php-8, laravel-10

I am encountering an error with my Laravel project, I have an API "my-origin/api/test", which is returning an Laravel blade view("View has react js modules") as JSON.

```json
{
  "html": "<link rel=\"preload\" as=\"style\" href=\"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/build\/assets\/app-6db13668.css\" \/><link rel=\"modulepreload\" href=\"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/build\/assets\/app-373d35cf.js\" \/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/build\/assets\/app-6db13668.css\" \/><script type=\"module\" src=\"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/build\/assets\/app-373d35cf.js\"><\/script>    <div id=\"root\"><\/div>"
}
```

now I am accessing this with other origin `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` it is giving an error related to CORS

> Access to script at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/assets/app-373d35cf.js` from origin `http://127.0.0.1:5500` has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am using Laravel 10 so it has already Cors.php and handleCors middleware which was define in kernel in

```php
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'cors' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
];
```

also I config Cors.php

```php
'paths' => ['*'],
```

and

```php
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
```

in my api.pp

```php
Route::middleware(["cors"])->group(function () {
    // my test api routes
});
```